# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string(When try to save XML data)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an XML file data as given below.

```
'<NewDataSet>
  <tblVCWS_Schedule>
    <PKWSSchedule>1</PKWSSchedule>    
    <ScheduleTime>PT7H</ScheduleTime>    
  </tblVCWS_Schedule>
  <tblVCWS_Schedule>
    <PKWSSchedule>2</PKWSSchedule>   
    <ScheduleTime>PT13H30M</ScheduleTime>    
  </tblVCWS_Schedule>
  <tblVCWS_Schedule>
    <PKWSSchedule>3</PKWSSchedule>    
    <ScheduleTime>PT13H30M</ScheduleTime>    
  </tblVCWS_Schedule> 
</NewDataSet>'
```

The ScheduleTime field is a time(7) data type field in SQL.

But when i try to save the data into a temporary table I am getting the

"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

```
 DECLARE @PreAdviceSubmissions  varchar(max) 

    set @PreAdviceSubmissions=
    '<NewDataSet>
      <tblVCWS_Schedule>
        <PKWSSchedule>1</PKWSSchedule>    
        <ScheduleTime>PT7H</ScheduleTime>    
      </tblVCWS_Schedule>
      <tblVCWS_Schedule>
        <PKWSSchedule>2</PKWSSchedule>   
        <ScheduleTime>PT13H30M</ScheduleTime>    
      </tblVCWS_Schedule>
      <tblVCWS_Schedule>
        <PKWSSchedule>3</PKWSSchedule>    
        <ScheduleTime>PT13H30M</ScheduleTime>    
      </tblVCWS_Schedule> 
    </NewDataSet>'

    DECLARE @hDoc int

        CREATE TABLE #PreAdviceSubmissions
        (   
           PKWSSchedule bigint,
           ScheduleTime Time(7)
        )

        EXECUTE sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @PreAdviceSubmissions

        INSERT INTO #PreAdviceSubmissions 
        (
           PKWSSchedule,
           ScheduleTime
        )
        SELECT 
           PKWSSchedule ,
           CAST(ScheduleTime AS TIME(7)) 
        FROM OPENXML(@hDoc,'/NewDataSet/tblVCWS_Schedule', 2)
        WITH 
        (
            PKWSSchedule  bigint 'PKWSSchedule' ,   
            ScheduleTime  Time(7) 'ScheduleTime'          
        )

        EXECUTE sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc

        select * from #PreAdviceSubmissions
```

Can anyone help to solve this issue? Please note i cant change the datatype Time(7) to any other data type.

Comment: you set ScheduleTime  like PT13H30M And its not a well formed.this value not convert to Time

Comment: How can i convert PT13H30M this to time ?I am getting the value as like that from the XML file?

Comment: TIME DATA TYPE WILL NOT ACCEPT STRING AS TIME IN SQL SERVER. YOU HAVE TO USE REPLACE IN CODE ITSELF AND CONVERT TO TIME.

Comment: @ArunKumar check my answer i think its solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    INSERT INTO #PreAdviceSubmissions 
    (
       PKWSSchedule,
       ScheduleTime
    )
    SELECT 
       PKWSSchedule ,
       CASE WHEN (SELECT CHARINDEX('%M%',ScheduleTime)) > 0 THEN 
       CONVERT(time(7),REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ScheduleTime,'PT',''),'H',':'),'M',''))
       ELSE
       CONVERT(time(7),REPLACE(REPLACE(ScheduleTime,'PT',''),'H',':00')) END
    FROM OPENXML(@hDoc,'/NewDataSet/tblVCWS_Schedule', 2)
    WITH 
    (
        PKWSSchedule  bigint 'PKWSSchedule' ,   
        ScheduleTime  Time(7) 'ScheduleTime'          
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @TIME VARCHAR(50) = 'PT13H30M'
```

IF (SELECT PATINDEX('%M%','@TIME') > 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT CONVERT(TIME,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@TIME,'PT',''),'H',':'),'M',''))
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT CONVERT(TIME,REPLACE(REPLACE(@TIME,'PT',''),'H',':00'))
END